Prometheus systemd expression based on a list of services
I have several VMs each exporting (using node-exporter) the status of its systemd services. I would like to have an alerting rule that looks something like:
      - alert: service_down
        expr: node_systemd_unit_state{name="$SERVICE.service",state="active"} != 1
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: major
        annotations:
          summary: "$SERVICE service is down on {{ $labels.instance }}"

Where Service will be taken from some pre-defined list. Is this possible?
The alternative of adding basically the same rule for the different services seems very inefficient and wasteful.
